# Show / hide div with sessions or cookie

Tags: php, cookies, html, hide, show

I need to hide or show a div that have a slideshow inside.
The idea is to give to the users a link for them to hide or show the div.

At the moment I call the slideshow on the body of the page with `<?php include('slideshow.php'); ?>`

After the user clicks on the link to hide/show the div I will like to call a second file ( 
`<?php include('no-slideshow.php'); ?>` ) which contain a diferent div.

As far as I had found there is no way to achieve this with sessions, or at least I did't find a solution to this problem.

My guess is that this need to be done with cookies, but I don't understend how.

Comment: didn't work with session ?!! can you put more code please ? ^^

Comment: I don't think that it can't be done with sessions. on what grounds do you suppose that It can't be done?

Comment: "didn't work with session ?!! can you put more code please ? ^^ – Awea" No idea of how to make it work with sessions, but if you now a way i will apriciate your help.

Comment: "I don't think that it can't be done with sessions. on what grounds do you suppose that It can't be done? – Headshota" No idea, but if you know a way i will apriciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use JavaScript only way to achieve that is to use link (requires page to be reloaded).

This is basic logic only, not a complete solution, but think you'll get the point.

Create a link on web page to the server-side script.

```
<a href="toggle_visibility.php">hide/show</a>
```

Create script **togle_visibility.php** to process user's request.

```
<?php

  $hidediv = isset($_COOKIE['hide_div']) && ($_COOKIE['hide_div'] == 'hide');
  $cookie_value = !$hidediv ? 'hide' : 'show';
  setcookie('hide_div', $cookie_value, time()+32000000); // cookie expires after year
  header('location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php');

?>
```

All you need now (after return to original page) is to check value stored in cookie and decide do you want od not to show that div to do user.

```
<?php

  ... more code

  $hidediv = isset($_COOKIE['hide_div']) && ($_COOKIE['hide_div'] == 'hide');
  if ($hidediv) {
    include('no-slideshow.php');
    }
  else {
    include('slideshow.php');
    }

  ... more code 

?>
```

*EDIT: $hidediv condition.*

It works if user has JavaScript disabled but doesn't work if cookies has been disabled in browser settings.

I did not check this code, so same typos are possible.

Comment: not working, i just get a 404 page not found on my site. Also this example will not work as it will not redirect the user to the page that he/she was browsing before click on the link

Comment: it works... I put it online for you to see http://www.service-kl.com/code/daniel/index.php... just adapt code to yourself. This is logically way not complete solution. We are here to help you, not to work for you.

Comment: Hi... thanks a lot, the problem with your code was the place where i had placed the toggle_visibility.php file. It works exelent. I own you a pint of Guinnes.

Comment: Sorry can you tell me if there is any way to reload the current page instead to redirect the user ?

Comment: @Daniel - Yes, you can use meta refresh (Google for it), but be aware that meta refresh may be disabled by client so in that case, your script will stop after setting cookie (client will not get your original page back reloaded). You can use AJAX to set cookie and get response from page with no reloading at all, but that solution requires your experience with Ajax/JavaScript. Also, there's more solutions but there's no one easier of this one on my mind now. However, you can always Google for more code and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood. You want to hide div once user cliks on a link?

Why are you not doing this using javascript? (hide/show the divs?)

Comment: because the div is inside of a file '<?php include('no-slideshow.php'); ?>' What I will like to achive is to include one of the followinf files depending on what the user clik - hide or show

Comment: Also i will like to make this work even if the user have javascript disabled

Answer (score 0):

This command will [set a cookie](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) named `include` with value `what to include`.

```
setcookie('include', 'what to include', time()+86400);
```

You can check this cookie before include like this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['include'])) {
    include($_COOKIE['include'] . '.php');
} else {
    include('slideshow.php');
}
```

*Note: because cookies can be easily faked you'll need to check twice what to include.*

Comment: Sorry but I don't undertend your example

Comment: @Daniel what's your question exactly?

Comment: All tha i need is a way to provide a link on the page so the users can hide or show a div. I will like to store that on a cookie but if it is possible to do this with sessions its ok for me.

Comment: There are two wiles slideshop.php and no-slideshow.php. Currently i call the slideshow.php file to show the slideshow. I will like to provide an option to switch betwen files (show/hide) and store that in a cookie or a session so users can browse the rest of the site witout see the slideshow. Also if there is some sort of page reloading or refresh i can't use something like header('location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php') because all that i need is to keep the user on the paga that he/she is currenlty viewing ( it may be any page on the site )